# Scope variable not binding in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not sure why this scope variable is not binding in my view.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Here is a [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/hotugoxoxu/edit?html,js,output) with the example.

---

Update: 03/21/16

As @Dsafds noted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36117387/1837874), I simply forgot to include the `$scope` parameter. Wish AngularJS had a lint tool!

Comment: did you try this, instead of scope? and did you try declaring the $scope in module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you forgot to import $scope:

```
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}]);
```

So it would work then..

```js
 var app = angular.module('example', []);

 app.controller('DemoCtrl', ["$scope",
   function($scope) {
     $scope.name = 'World';
   }
 ]);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not use `$scope` as a parameter in the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('example', []);

DemoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope']; // <----- Add annotation
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function DemoCtrl($scope) { //<------- Add $scope here
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

See the working [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bokosaceyu/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

pass **`$scope`** as dependency in controller function.

```
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```